# Function arguments in directive with templateUrl

Tags: angularjs

I created a custom directive with an isolated scope that binds to a function from the enclosing controller and with references to a templateUrl. Here's what my code looks like:

the html

```
<div ng-controller='MyCtrl as my'>
    <custom-directive data='my.data' on-search="my.find(param1, param2)"></custom-directive>
</div>
```

the directive

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {

    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            data : '=data'
            search : '&onSearch',
        },
        templateUrl : 'customDirective.html'
    };
});
```

the template

```
<div>
    <input ng-model='data.id'>
    <a ng-click='find(param1, param2)'></a>

</div>
```

The arguments received by function `find` is also stored in `data`. The controller `data` binds to the directive but not the function. My log inside the function won't even show.

It seems there are different ways to do it as I have seen in many examples (see below) but none seems to work in my case.

Example 1: pass a mapping of parameter and values in the template

```
<div>
    <input ng-model='data.id'>
    <a ng-click='find.({param1: data.value1, param2: data.value2})'></a>

</div>
```

Example 2: put a link in the directive

```
app.directive('customDirective', function() {

    return {
        restrict : 'E',
        scope : {
            data : '=data'
            search : '&onSearch',
        },
        templateUrl : 'customDirective.html',
        link : function(scope, elem, attr) {
            scope.retrieve({param1: scope.data.value1,
                            param2: scope.data.value2});
        }

    };
});
```

Example 3 : use scope.$apply(), $parse in link but haven't tried this

Could someone show me how to do it and also explain to me the `link` part (I don't understand that part) and if you're feeling generous, show the working alternatives as shown by the examples. Thanks

Comment: (1) `find.(stuff)` is wrong syntax - the dot should not be there. (2) Is there a function `find` in the scope of the directive? From the setup, the function is called `search`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos (1) corrected the '.', that's just a typo (2) the function `find` is in the controller, I'm passing that as the `search` of the directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to passe params for your function just the reference so in your html

```
<custom-directive data='my.data' on-search="my.find"></custom-directive>
```

and your template directive directly call

```
<div>
    <input ng-model='data.id'>
    <a ng-click='find(data.value1, data.value2)'></a>
</div>
```

I also suggest you to use $scope and not the controller. So in your controller define

```
$scope.data = {
    id: 1,
    value1: "value1",
    value2: "value2"
}

$scope.find = function (param1, param2) {
   //Your logic
}
```

And in your template put directly

```
<custom-directive data='data' on-search="find"></custom-directive>
```

I hope this answer to your question

About link this text from angular js doc is pretty clear I think

> Directives that want to modify the DOM typically use the link option.
> link takes a function with the following signature, function
> link(scope, element, attrs) { ... } where:
>
> scope is an Angular scope object. element is the jqLite-wrapped
>
> element that this directive matches.
> attrs is a hash object with key-value pairs of normalized attribute names and their
> corresponding attribute values.
>
> In our link function, we want to update the
> displayed time once a second, or whenever a user changes the time
> formatting string that our directive binds to. We will use the
> $interval service to call a handler on a regular basis. This is easier
> than using $timeout but also works better with end-to-end testing,
> where we want to ensure that all $timeouts have completed before
> completing the test. We also want to remove the $interval if the
> directive is deleted so we don't introduce a memory leak.

Comment: I'm not using `$scope`. I'm using `var self=this; self.methodName = function...` to expose my controller methods. Your suggestion seems to work if I use `$scope` but not with my current setup. I will have to change too many things, including the ones I didn't work on if I change to `$scope`. Any idea how to make this work using `this.methodName`?